# Task "default" is not in your gulpfile

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I run gulp in my console I got this error:

> Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile

My gulpfile looks just fine:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    LiveServer = require('gulp-live-server'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('live-server', function () {
    var server = new LiveServer('server/main.js');
    server.start();
});

gulp.task('serve', ['live-server'], function () {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:3000",
        port: 9001
    });
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you just run `gulp` in your console it will look for a default task to run. You only defined `live-server` and `serve` as tasks.

To solve define a default task, you can add the task you actually want to run as the dependency like so:

```
gulp.task( 'default', [ 'serve' ] )
```

Now if you run `gulp` it will run the `default` task which in turn runs the `serve` task. Alternatively you can just run `gulp serve` and it will work as well.

Comment: Very usefull plugin if you have lots of task in your config file is [gulp-help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-help), that will serve as your helper when you type plain "gulp" for example, listing you all available commands.

Answer (score 4):

Please include this in your gulp file.

```
gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 2):

Create a default task and add tasks you would like to run by default:

```
gulp.task("default", function () {
  gulp.start("serve");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and this is my gulp file

[image: My gulp file]

Instead of having a 'default' task, what i do is directly calling the 'serve' task.

In cmd -> `gulp serve`

By directly calling the serve, it would call the browser-sync task for me.

Hope this would be helpful for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Here was mine before...

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var bundleConfig = require('./bundleconfig.json');

const REGEX = {
    css: /\.css$/,
    js: /\.js$/
};

gulp.task('min:js', async function () {
    merge(getBundles(REGEX.js).map(bundle => {
        return gulp.src(bundle.inputFiles, { base: '.' })
            .pipe(concat(bundle.outputFileName))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
    }))
});

gulp.task('min:css', async function () {
    merge(getBundles(REGEX.css).map(bundle => {
        return gulp.src(bundle.inputFiles, { base: '.' })
            .pipe(concat(bundle.outputFileName))
            .pipe(cssmin())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
    }))
});

const getBundles = (regexPattern) => {
    return bundleConfig.filter(bundle => {
        return regexPattern.test(bundle.outputFileName);
    });
};

gulp.task('minify', gulp.series(['min:js', 'min:css']));
```

#### And then after, literally just had to change the last line to 'default' smh

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var bundleConfig = require('./bundleconfig.json');

const REGEX = {
    css: /\.css$/,
    js: /\.js$/
};

gulp.task('min:js', async function () {
    merge(getBundles(REGEX.js).map(bundle => {
        return gulp.src(bundle.inputFiles, { base: '.' })
            .pipe(concat(bundle.outputFileName))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
    }))
});

gulp.task('min:css', async function () {
    merge(getBundles(REGEX.css).map(bundle => {
        return gulp.src(bundle.inputFiles, { base: '.' })
            .pipe(concat(bundle.outputFileName))
            .pipe(cssmin())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
    }))
});

const getBundles = (regexPattern) => {
    return bundleConfig.filter(bundle => {
        return regexPattern.test(bundle.outputFileName);
    });
};

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['min:js', 'min:css']));
```